# create dynamic frameset and frame with javascript

Tags: javascript, frameset

I've a problem with a dynamic creation of frameset and frame, I'm write these simple script:

```
        function createframe(){ 
        var ahead = document.head;
        var mainfs = document.createElement('FRAMESET');
        mainfs.setAttribute("name", "mainframeset");
        mainfs.setAttribute("id", "mfs");
        mainfs.setAttribute("cols", "50,*");
        ahead.appendChild(mainfs);
        for ( var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          var ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
          ifrm.setAttribute("src", "www.facebook.it"); 
          document.getElementById('mfs').appendChild(ifrm);
}
```

And put in head of blank html page, but won't work!

any suggestion?

Comment: Add http:// for your src link. Without http://, the browser interpretates a local source link.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but still it does not work!

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: nono nothing, no error and no warning but nothing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending your frameset to the head of the html file, so nothing will appear.
But your function is not working, because it's not closed yet, a "}" is missing at last.
Also you need to add an event Listener, like so :

```
window.addEventListener("load", createframe, false);
```

Here's a jsfiddle link for you: [Try It](https://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/t1L0veL0/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I forgot to write the last }, but in the original code there is...I had already solved by inserting a button, but your solution seems much better ... thanks again